# Google Assistant API stopped responding to "Ok google". Stuck on MEDIA_STATE_IDLE

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk

I've been using the Gogle Assistant SDK on my raspberry pi for the last three days. All of a sudden it has stoped responding to the prompt. I'm using the sample hotword.py with some custom code.

Here's a list of everything I've done leading up to it stopping working:

-Changed my code controlling my light from using os.system to start a program to controlling the light directly in the program. This included:

-Pip install RPi.GPIO in the env/bin/activate source

-Importing that library into the sample code from google

-Accessing credentials for firebase from the program

After doing those things I rebooted the pi as I start assistent at launch with this .sh

```
#!/bin/bash

source env/bin/activate
cd assistant-sdk-python/google-assistant sdk/googlesamples/assistant/library

python hotword.py --device-model-id {model id}
```

It shows this expected result but ignores prompts

```
ok (shown in below code)
device_model_id: {model id}
device_id: {device id}

ON_MUTED_CHANGED:
  {"is_muted": false}
ON_MEDIA_STATE_IDLE
ON_START_FINISHED
```

I reverted the code and installs but that did not fix it. I'm not sure if this stuff caused a problem but I thought it was worth mentioning.

I also turned up mic sensitivity with export ASSISTANT_MIC_SENSITIVITY=-6

Here's some of hotword.py

```
# My imports
import RPi.GPIO as IO        

import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

#start my code --------------------------------------------------------

cred = credentials.Certificate('/path-to-certificate')
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL' : 'https://myproject.firebaseio.com/'
})

IO.setwarnings(False)          
IO.setmode (IO.BOARD) 

IO.setup(16,IO.OUT)

p = IO.PWM(16,50)

root = db.reference()

print("ok")

#end my code ----------------------------------------------------------

def process_event(event):

    if event.type == EventType.ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_STARTED:
        print()

    print(event)

    if event.type == EventType.ON_DEVICE_ACTION:
        for command, params in event.actions:

            print('Do command', command, 'with params', str(params))

        #My code start ----------------------------------------------------------------

           if command == "action.devices.commands.OnOff":

                if params['on']:
                    print('Turning the LED on.')

                    currentVal = root.child('currentVal').get()
                    onVal = root.child('onAngle').get()

                    if(currentVal != onVal):
                        root.child('currentVal').set(onVal)
                        root.child('value').set(onVal)
                        p.ChangeDutyCycle(float(onVal))
                        time.sleep(0.5)
                        p.ChangeDutyCycle(0)    

            else:
               #same as above different angles   

        #My code end ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Sorry if this is too much code, I have no idea whats causing the problem in listening

The issue is still open on github at https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/316
People seem to be having the issue on sdk v.1.01 and not v1. My mic is working I verified with arecord.

Thanks for any help.